# How to identify similar rows in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to find out how to compare elements of my `df1` with `df2` and count their frequency. My `df1` and `df2` are like this:

```
var1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) 
var2 = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) 
value = c(0, 0.75, 0.51, 0.42, 0.31, 0.22, 0.11)
freq = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1) 
df1 = data.frame(var1, var2, value, freq)

var1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) 
var2 = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8) 
value = c(0, 0.75, 0.42, 0.41, 0.31, 0, 0)
freq = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1) 
df2 = data.frame(var1, var2, value, freq)
```

so I would like a `df3` with rows that are similar in `df1` and `df2`

From the above example `df3` would be:

```
var1=c(1,5)
var2=c(1,4)
value=c(0,0.31) 
freq=c(1,1)
df3=data.frame(var1, var2, value, freq)
```

Comment: Their frequency in what dataframe? df1? df2?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan good question! I updated my example - but the freq do not need to match just var1, var2 and value, The freq in df3= freq [df1] + freq[df2]

Comment: If it should be (freq in df1) + (freq in df2) then your desired output (df3) should have 2 as the frequency instead of 1 right?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

```
library(dplyr)

df3 = df1[apply(df1 == df2, 1, all), ]
df3 %>% group_by_all() %>% summarise(freq= n())
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the frequency part this is just a merge with default settings (i.e. inner join on all variables). To get the frequency part you can use `count` after grouping by all variables, then `inner_join` (dplyr merge equivalent) and add the individual frequencies.

I modified df1 just to check that the count part works as intended.

```
merge(df1, df2)
#    var1 var2 value
# 1:    1    1  0.00
# 2:    5    4  0.31

library(dplyr)

df1 <- df1[c(1, 1, seq(nrow(df1))),]

df1 %>% 
  group_by_all %>% 
  count(name = 'n1') %>% 
  inner_join(
    df2 %>% 
      group_by_all %>% 
      count(name = 'n2')
  ) %>% 
  mutate(n = n1 + n2) %>% 
  select(-n1, -n2)

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
# # Groups:   var1, var2, value [2]
#    var1  var2 value     n
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1     1  0        4
# 2     5     4  0.31     2
```

Comment: many thanks for your help -apologise for this - but I am struggling with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61187493/identify-consecutive-sequences-based-on-a-given-variable question. I have no clue how to indetify consecutive sequences based on a given variable. Any help is welcomed. many thanks