# Identify consecutive sequences based on a given variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I am literally stuck on this. The `df1` has the following variables:

1. `serial` = Group of people
2. `id1` = the person from the group (eg. `12 (serial) 1 (id1)` =group `12 person 1; 12 2 = group 12 person 2, etc`. )
3. `'Day`'when the first (or start) recording was made.

The days consist of equal number of observations (eg.95)

```
        day1 (Monday)  =  day11-day196 
        day2 (Tuesday) = day21-day296     
        day3 (Wednesday) =  day31-day396   
        day4 (Thursday) =  day41-day496   
        day5 (Friday) = day51-day596      
        day6 (Saturday) = day61-day696   
        day7 (Sunday) =  day71-day796
```

Example of df1

```
serial id1  Day     day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6 day7
12      1   Monday    2    1    2    1    1    3    1
123     1   Tuesday   0    3    0    3    3    0    3
10      1   Wednesday 0    3    3    3    3    3    3
```

I would like to identify the consecutive records (there is no gap between the daily records) and the total amount of the records.

The starting day for consecutive recordings is the 'Day` variable. For example a consecutive record would be serial 12. Recording started on Monday and there are records (at leas one from 95 variable) during the week. During the week (7 x 95 variable) there were made 11 records

A non-consecutive record would be id 123 as the there is a gap day on day3 and day6. Record started on  Tuesday and there is a gap  on Wednesday and Saturday.

Finally I would like to record the duration of the consecutive recording.

Sample output:

```
 serial  id1   Duration Occurance        Days
12       1      11        7        day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6 day7
123      1      12        0        0
10       1      18        5        day3 day4 day5 day6 day7
```

Sample data

```
structure(list(serial = c(12, 123, 10), id1 = c(1, 1, 1), Day = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Monday",
"Tuesday", "Wednesday"), class = "factor"), day1 = c(2, 0, 0),
day2 = c(1, 3, 3), day3 = c(2, 0, 3), day4 = c(1, 3, 3),
day5 = c(1, 3, 3), day6 = c(3, 0, 3), day7 = c(1, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA,
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Similar post [R - identify consecutive sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439273/r-identify-consecutive-sequences)

Comment: looks similar to another question i answered yesterday

Comment: If there are columns until day796, I just wonder, how many values you would consider as consescutive

Comment: Consider that a row is `2 1 0 1 0 5 3 4 3 2 1 7 5 0 1 3 2 4 3 5 7 9 0 1 3 4 2 4 2 7 9..`

Comment: in your example the second row matches to which day

Comment: the confusion is that you have a mappiing table for days that start from day11 and your iinput example is less than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to get the 'Occurance' correct

```
library(data.table)
wkdays <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")

out1 <-  do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) {
              i1 <- match(y, wkdays): length(x)
              i2 <- x[i1] != 0
              i3 <- all(i2)
              grp1 <- rleid(i2)
              Days <- if(i3) tapply(names(x)[i1][i2], grp1[i2], FUN = paste, collapse= ' ') else ''
             Occurance <- if(i3) length(grp1[i2]) else 0
             data.frame(Occurance, Days)
            }, asplit(df[-(1:3)], 1), df$Day))

 out1$Duration <- rowSums(df1[startsWith(names(df1), 'day')])
 out1
 # Occurance                               Days Duration
 #1         7 day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6 day7       11
 #2         0                                          12
 #3         5           day3 day4 day5 day6 day7       18
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `lead` and `lag` of `dplyr`,

I tried it on my side and here is the result:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    select(serial, contains("day", ignore.case = FALSE)) %>% 
    group_by(serial) %>% 
    tidyr::gather(day, val, -serial) %>% 
    # convert to binary 
    mutate(occur = ifelse(val > 0, 1, 0)) %>% 
    # if detect a seq, add cumulative, else 0
    mutate(cums = ifelse(lead(occur) > 0 & lag(occur) > 0 & occur > 0, 
                         occur + cumsum(occur), 0)) %>% 
    summarise(occurance = max(cums, na.rm = T), duration = sum(val))
```

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  serial occurance duration
   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1     10         6       18
2     12         7       11
3    123         0       12
```

Comment: many thanks maybe this is a big ask but how can I return the sequence days?

Comment: You can find out which row the maximum "occurrence" is at (using `which`) and works backwards to retrieve the respective rows. This is sort of a hack-ish way of doing it. Since you are fundamentally dealing with sequences, I recommend you to convert your data into time-series format and use relevant packages.

Comment: one more question please how can I group the results based on id so as in sample output. Basically instead of... summarise(occurance = max(cums, na.rm = T), duration = sum(val))...how can I receive an output wit id (grouped) occurance and duration. thank you for your time

Comment: do you mean that you want to group both with serial and id? Just do it directly `group_by(serial, id)`.

Comment: yes I do need both as serial and id1 define an individual observation - i think we need to create an index for this

Comment: but how can i see the result ordered based on (serial id1) occurance and duration ..at this moment this line ..mutate(cums = ifelse(lead(occur) > 0 & lag(occur) > 0 & occur > 0, 
                         occur + cumsum(occur), 0))...the order is done based on day